# Incompatible Installer project in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio

I have an installer project for WCF service. It was working on my machine with VS 2013 , now I moved to another PC, but it says it is incompatible with the version of visual studio [visual studio 2013 also] as below snap shows :

[image: Visual Studio Incompatible project]

Answer (score 0):

This link will install installer project extension, close VS first then open it again

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d/file/130817/3/VSI_bundle.exe